# Unable to center label using auto layout for 3.5 and 4 inch iPhone displays

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a label and activity indicator in the middle of my view. See below.

[image]

This is fine on a 4 inch display (iPhone 5X). However if I run the project on a 3.5 inch display (iPhone 4X) the label and activity indicator is not in the middle of the screen anymore. See below.

[image]

Auto layout is enabled, am I missing some constraints for this?

Comment: I am using auto layout. I'm guessing I need to add constraints but dont know where to add them.

Answer (score 2):

Try to explore [Auto Layouts in iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/).

The problem you've got appears because of the Views/Labels are not adapting/stretching/squeezing depentently on parent container.

Comment: I am using auto layout. Do I need to add a constraint?

Answer (score 2):

Using AutoLayout, you can setup alignment constraints.  If you Add New Alignment Constraints for Vertical and Horizontal Center in Container, they should center on the screen.  (I don't have enough reputation to post a picture, but the button is to the left of the "add constraints" button in Xcode: It is a vertical bar with two left-aligned boxes next to it.)